# Thread safe collection with fixed capacity in FIFO order

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

Problem: Maintain a collection with a fixed capacity ( say 2 elements ), which is accessible across 100+ threads concurrently.

Always store latest elements from recent thread. Once they are stored, write a method to check if all these elements are duplicate.

My solution : `BlockingQueue` with fixed capacity and implement custom add method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FixedBlockingQueue<T extends Object> {

    final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private int capacity;

    public FixedBlockingQueue(int capacity){
        super();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(capacity);
        System.out.println("Capactiy:"+this.capacity);
    }
    public void addElement(T element){
        try{
            if ( queue.size() > capacity - 1 ){
                queue.remove();         
            }
            queue.put(element);
            for ( Iterator it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                System.out.println(it.next());
            }
            System.out.println("________");
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FixedBlockingQueue<Integer> f = new FixedBlockingQueue<Integer>(2);
        for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            f.addElement(i);
        }

    }   
}
```

output:

```
0
________
0
1
________
1
2
________
2
3
________
3
4
________
4
5
________
5
6
________
6
7
________
7
8
________
8
9
```

From output, you can clearly see that first element is getting removed and recent element is getting added to Queue.

***My query : Is it the good solution ? or is there any other nice solution, works better than this?***

**EDIT:** In this scenario of frequent deletions, is `ArrayBlockingQueue` better than `LinkedBlockingQueue`?

Comment: Your task does not include that the collection should be threadsafe? Because yours isn't. Threads can get stuck inserting because the check whether something needs to be removed first isn't atomic.

Comment: Calling ```queue.size()``` is O(N) for linked-list types - since you're doing this every time you add you're not really getting the benefit of being a linked list.

Comment: @Matthew it's O(1) for `LinkedBlocking(De)Queue` (and `ArrayBlockginQueue` which is what is used in this code) because they store and update the size whenever the collection is modified. It's indeed O(n) for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and some others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's avoid reinventing the wheel, just use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with a fixed capacity, it is a thread safe `FIFO` `BlockingQueue`. More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue(int)).

The problem with your code is that you do the following operations not atomically such that you can face race condition issues with it:

```
if ( queue.size() > capacity - 1 ){
    queue.remove();         
}
queue.put(element);
```

You need to wrap it into a `synchronized` block or use an explicit `Lock` to protect it as it is a critical section and we don't want multiple threads to call it concurrently.

Here is how it can be done with a `BlockingQueue`:

```
BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(2);
for ( int i=0; i< 10; i++){
    // Try to add the object and return immediately if it is full
    // then if it could not be added,
    // remove the last element of the queue and try again
    while (!queue.offer(i, 0L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)) {
        queue.remove();
    }
    for ( Iterator it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    System.out.println("________");
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
________
0
1
________
1
2
________
2
3
________
3
4
________
4
5
________
5
6
________
6
7
________
7
8
________
8
9
________
```

Comment: How does old element get deleted? I did not find code in grepcode insert() method.

Comment: `LinkedBlockingQueue`'s `put` method waits(blocks) if necessary for space to become available. It doesn't remove excess element.

Comment: In this case, the queue size is > 2 if I set the capacity as 2?

Comment: it is a BlockingQueue so if you try to add an object when the queue is full, the calling thread will wait until another thread consumes an element of the queue

Comment: Actually my consumer thread just checks top X elements ( 2 elements for example if capacity = 2) and just leave. I don't have mechanism to consume the element as of now. I will try to add it now.

Comment: And one last doubt. Is capacity act as threshold? At any point of time, can I have more elements than Capacity?

Comment: When you remove an element and try next offer, other thread can put successfully. That will change the order in queue. Still have race condition.

Comment: @doge that's right but you never can define the order in the queue anyway as you cannot know which thread will acquire the lock first so your remark is not valid in practice

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto, Still I think ArrayBlockingQueue is better than LinkedBlockingQueue due to frequent deletions in my use case.

Comment: the code proposed above still works with an ArrayBlockingQueue

Comment: Right, though class is not thread-safe, in this case it seems tolerable.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit first that I never used a BlockingQueue from the concurrent package, but I have done multi-threaded programming before.

I believe there's a problem here:

```
if ( queue.size() > capacity - 1 ){
  queue.remove();         
}
```

If there are multiple threads running this method concurrently, then multiple threads could do this check and it could evaluate to true for a good number of them before they take action. So in that case, `remove()` could be called more times than you anticipate.

Basically, if you want to keep your logic that way, you will have to find a way to ensure that it isn't possible for another Thread to change the size of the queue between the time you check the size and then perform an operation on it, such as removing an element.

One way to fix this might be to wrap it in a synchronized block like so:

```
synchornized (queue) {
  if ( queue.size() > capacity - 1 ){
    queue.remove();         
  }
  queue.put(element);
  for ( Iterator it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    System.out.println(it.next());
  }
  System.out.println("________");
}
```

This ensures that `queue` doesn't get accessed by other threads after you check the current size of it. Keep in mind that the more stuff that you have synchronized, the longer that other threads will have to wait before performing operations on it, which could slow down your program. You can read more about this keyword [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: Hmm. I have tested two threads in separate program. I will increase the threads. Can you propose an alternative?

Comment: This isn't something that you would see happen very often with just 2 threads. But if you threw a ton of threads at it, eventually you might see an inconsistency.